# @scheduled throwing exception for cron expression

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, scheduler, spring-scheduled

Team,

I have put the cron expression in the properties file. Then I tried referring that cron expression from a java file as shown.

```
    @Scheduled(cron=  "${cron.expression}" )
    public void test(){
    ...
    }
```

It threw me the following error:

```
Cron expression must consist of 6 fields (found 1 in "${cron.expression}"
```

I'm new to this scheduler. Please advice on how to make this expression configurable.

Thanks

Comment: What is your cron expression in properties file?

Comment: how did you configrue your properties file?

Comment: cron.expression = 0 0/15 * * * * 
This is the cron expression in my properties file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added the following in my AppConfig java file.

```
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
```

Without the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer, we can access the properties file only using Autowired environment variables. But using the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer, we can make use of property file variables using ${..}.

With this logic my code started working like a charm.

Thanks for your replies @S.B and @RaphaelRoth.